# 4 logo in title page in one row

Tags: graphics, floats, logos

Currently I am trying to set four figures in one row, but I could not. Can anybody help me?
My figures are two companies' logos with their sub-department.There are no labels or names required.

The first and fourth figures should be main and right to first figure its sub-department similarly left from the fourth figure its sub-department. Also the second and third figures should have the same size.

[image]

packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} %

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \clearpage
        \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{Bilder/UNI-Logo_Siegel_4c_RZ_06.pdf}
            \end{minipage}    
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=2.0\textwidth]{Bilder/com.pdf}
            \end{minipage}  
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Bilder/logo_Be.pdf}
            \end{minipage}   
        \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{Bilder/rdlogo.pdf}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Don't put the `figure` environment inside of a `center` environment. You don't need the `figure` environment in this case, it is only useful if you want the figure to float, and if you want to use a `\caption`. In your case you want control over where exactly the images end up and don't want to use a `\caption`, so don't use a `figure` environment.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand. Could you please edit my code which I have posted? Thank you very much. I add packages which I am using in quaetion.

Comment: I honestly do not understand how you want the figures arranged. Could you specify that in more detail?

Comment: I've amended your post to make your question include a minimal working example (MWE).  You should always include an example of your problem which can be cut-and-paste and compiled; it makes it much easier for people to help you.  Your example should cut out anything that isn't relevant to your problem, which in this case is figure arrangement.  Reading an explanation of MWEs would be a good idea.

Comment: hi  @ Michael Chatiskatzi i uploaded figure to understand better. There are four figures of logo. i need to give in my title page in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this problem.  I assume that you're trying to build a title page (since you've wrapped your example up in `titlepage` tags), which means you don't need to muck around with `figure` and such.  `figure` is for *floats*; that is, for displays which might appear somewhere in the document other than where they are included in the code.  Titlepages will always be in the same place.

So your solution is simple:  Make sure that each of your images is assigned an appropriate width, so that all four of them together total `1.0\textwidth`, and you're done:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} %

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Bilder/UNI-Logo_Siegel_4c_RZ_06.pdf}%
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Bilder/com.pdf}%
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Bilder/logo_Be.pdf}%
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Bilder/rdlogo.pdf}%
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

We don't have your images, of course, so I've used the `draft` option; you may need to adjust the sizes.  But this does ensure that the second and third images are the same size, as you noted had to happen.  The above yields the following:

[image: Results of compiling above code]

Note here the `%` at the end of each line; this prevents LaTeX from inserting a space between the images.  If you want spaces, you'll have to adjust the widths of the images appropriately, so that the total width of the line is `1.0\textwidth`.  For example:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Bilder/UNI-Logo_Siegel_4c_RZ_06.pdf}%
\hskip0.05\textwidth%
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Bilder/com.pdf}%
\hskip0.05\textwidth%
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Bilder/logo_Be.pdf}%
\hskip0.05\textwidth%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Bilder/rdlogo.pdf}%
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: your code is working but due to the large size of the logos, they are not coming in a row inaccurate manner. The fourth photo is going half out of the page. Do you have any suggestions for that?  I have uploaded another photo in question if the first one not possible. Furthermore these logos are in heading not in centre of the page. i have personal details on title page after logos. Thank you very much

Comment: logo in heading just for one title page not for all pages in document.

Comment: The `width` option should prevent them from protruding, if their metadata (giving their actual width) is accurate.  Are you sure you have the correct width settings?  You may have to massage the `width` values if the images themselves are wrong.  As for other details, this code is agnostic about where on the title page it's going.  Just enter more details, and the row will go up as the rest of the page is filled.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. how i can check the width of the image?  i have in pdf format and its not giving such detail. Thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: If it's a pdf, you can run `pdfinfo` on it.  I couldn't say more without knowing your system and your available tools.  If all else fails, just adjust the width setting of your images until they fit the way you want.

Comment: Thank you very much